# showing {"error":"Unauthenticated."} on laravel api call

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

showing {"error":"Unauthenticated."}, while calling larvel API in Laravel 5.4 and passport version: v1.0.9, using ajax call.

Calling from route api: 
Route::get('category/get_tree_data', 'CategoryApiController@getTreeData')->middleware('auth:api');

Answer (score 1):

If you set up Laravel Passport properly, you should have this in your view:[image]

You need to create a client, that client has a client id and a client secret.

Now you need to open your consumer app which shall contain your client id and your client secret.

It looks like this(you have to change the token and id to your specific one):

```
class OAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        $query = http_build_query([
            'client_id' => 3,
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/app/public/callback',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'scope' => '',
        ]);

        return redirect('http://localhost/app/public/oauth/authorize?' . $query);
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        $http = new Client;

        $response = $http->post('http://localhost/app/public/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => 3, // from admin panel above
                'client_secret' => 'BcTgzw6YiwWUaU8ShX4bMTqej9ccgoA4NU8a2U9j', // from admin panel above
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/app/public/callback',
                'code' => $request->code // Get code from the callback
            ]
        ]);

        return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    }
}
```

Now you need to call that consumer app and authorize your application.

[image]

If that worked you get an access token + a refresh token.

It should look like this:

[image]

Now you can test this using a program like postman.

You basically call your get route and add the access token, which gives you access to the api, like this:

[image]

If you have any more question I recommend reading the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport).

Thus I highly recommend watching following [video](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) from Taylor Otwell.

Of course you can give me a comment aswell if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code inside your `/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` file

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'),
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

working perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with Laravel 5.8 when calling `/api/user` on `auth:api` middleware, I've tried to call the API url using Postman but got `unauthenticated` message

And I am able to fixed it by changing the `hash` value to `false` in `config/auth.php` file

```
// routes/api.php
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

```
// config/auth.php
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false, // <-- change this to false
        ],
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.

In my case, I was caching generated token after user login.

```php
$token = $user->createToken('API'.'-'.strtoupper($user->username).'-'.'-X-AUTH-TOKEN', [$this->scope]);

Cache::add(strtoupper($user->username).'-'. 'X-TOKEN', $token->accessToken, $expiresAt);
```

After debugging, tried clearing cache

```php
Cache::clear();
```

and it's working now.

Comment: can you  please expand this answer with why this answers the OP question?